# Terminator custom commands cause shell to close

Tags: terminator

I have the default terminator profile configured to split the window into four quadrants on launch, this works well.

There is also a "Custom Command" option for each terminal, which I assumed meant something to run in the terminal. However, if I put anything in there, the command executes and the terminal closes (I'm sure it's executing because I've tried `echo hi > /tmp/hi`, and that file is indeed created with "hi" in it).

How can I get each terminal to execute a command I specify but remain open afterwards?

EDIT: Kubuntu 14.04.1, with the standard terminator distribution in the trusty repo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There an `When command exits:` option in Preferences → Profiles → Command. If you want to open shell after command executes, append `; bash` to custom command (e.g. `echo hi > /tmp/hi; bash`).

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those options work if I want to, for example, cd somewhere so I'm ready to go.

Comment: `cd /; bash` works for me. Maybe your `.bashrc` contains cd command?

Comment: cd was a bad exa,[;e as most shells will open in the same directory they were launched from, but the point is it's opening a _new_ shell. I feel like there should be a way to say "In this shell, execute these commands, just like I had typed them at the command line, and then leave the shell as it is"

Comment: Set custom command to `CUSTOM_CMD=1 bash`, and add [this](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=s47xv6J4) to your `.bashrc`. It's not quite the same (commands are not echoed), but you can define functions, variables, shell options, etc.

Comment: Hm, seems a little brittle but it'll work for me, maybe change your answer to your last comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*@xzfc's comment within his accepted answer helped me find a solution.*

---

Within each "custom command" field, enter

```
INITIAL_TERMINATOR_WINDOW=1 bash
```

Then, from within your `.bashrc` you can check to see if the variable is set, and respond accordingly:

```
if [ -n "$INITIAL_TERMINATOR_WINDOW" ]; then
  # Do something from an initial window
else
  # Do something different when opening subsequent windows
fi
```